# Spring, Hibernate Lazy Loading, sessionFactory, and OpenSessionInViewFilter

Tags: hibernate, spring, lazy-loading

I am using Hibernate's lazy loading, and am getting sessionFactory missing exception, even after I have defined a filter in web.xml to use OpenSessionInViewFilter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
       org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter
    </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping> 
</web-app>
```

My servlet-context.xml has following session and transaction manager definitions:

```
<beans:bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">${connection.dialect}</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
       </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>example.EntityA</beans:value>
            <beans:value>example.EntityB</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</beans:bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

I still get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'sessionFactory' is defined
```

I have tried defining a sessionFactoryBeanName attribute but results don't change. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare `sessionFactory` in the root web application context (i. e. `/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml`) to make it available to `OpenSessionInViewFilter`.

Comment: This works. Is there a way to bring all the filter settings to servlet-context.xml as well, thus not having to define sessionfactory in root-context.xml? Thanks

Comment: @Loke: No. `OpenSessionInViewFilter` is invoked before request reaches servlet, therefore filter cannot access servlet-specific stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put sesstionFactory Bean in your servlet-context.xml

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
<property name="annotatedClasses">
    .....
</property>
<property name="hibernateProperties">
    ......
</property>
<property name="schemaUpdate" value="true" />
```

Comment: My session-Factory is already **in** servlet-context.xml. As @axtavt suggested, I could fix it by defining sessionFactory in root-context.xml. If you are able to keep sessionFactory in servlet-context.xml, would you share your filter definitions, and the file in which you define them?

Answer (score 0):

This is the code fragment inside the `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter` class that looks up the `sessionFactory` bean :

```
/**
 * Look up the SessionFactory that this filter should use.
 * <p>The default implementation looks for a bean with the specified name
 * in Spring's root application context.
 * @return the SessionFactory to use
 * @see #getSessionFactoryBeanName
 */
protected SessionFactory lookupSessionFactory() {
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("Using SessionFactory '" + getSessionFactoryBeanName() + "' for OpenSessionInViewFilter");
    }
    WebApplicationContext wac = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(getServletContext());
    return wac.getBean(getSessionFactoryBeanName(), SessionFactory.class);
}
```

You'll notice that it uses the `WebApplicationContextUtils` class to load the session factory bean. The API (http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/WebApplicationContextUtils.html) for this class states :

> Convenience methods for retrieving the **root WebApplicationContext** for a given ServletContext. This is useful for programmatically accessing a Spring application context from within custom web views or MVC actions.
>
> Note that there are more convenient ways of accessing the root context
>   for many web frameworks, either part of Spring or available as an
>   external library. This helper class is just the most generic way to
>   access the root context.

Thus you are required to declare the `sessionFactory` in the root context if you wish to use the Spring provided `OpenSessionInViewFilter` feature out of the box.