# Is it possible to configure OpenSessionInViewFilter in Spring application context so that context:property-placeholder is useable?

Tags: spring-mvc, dependency-injection, applicationcontext, open-session-in-view, deployment-descriptor

**Initial situation**

My web application consists of the Maven modules *myapp-persistence*(.jar), *myapp-model*(.jar), *myapp-service*(.jar) and *myapp-web*(.war) to get a conventional, loosely coupled, multi-tiered architecture. All modules are joined together by a parent Maven module, which only contains the parent *POM* with general definitions for all sub modules.

Especially *myapp-service*(.jar) and *myapp-persistence*(.jar) hold their own configurable (!) application context parts with the needed objects. Both jars must be deployable with the containing variable definitions, in other words the jars must not have concrete values for the variables.

*myapp-service-context.xml* declares a *solrServer* bean with the variable of the server URL:

```xml
<bean id="solrServer" class="org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer">
    <constructor-arg value="${solr.serverUrl}" />
    <property name="connectionTimeout" value="60000"/>
    <property name="defaultMaxConnectionsPerHost" value="40"/>
    <property name="maxTotalConnections" value="40"/>
</bean>
```

*myapp-persistence-context.xml* defines a *dataSource* with connection variables:

```xml
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">      
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />       
</bean>
...
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    ...
</bean>
```

*myapp-web*(.war) references *myapp-service*(.jar) and *myapp-persistence*(.jar). In *myapp-servlet.xml* it includes their application context parts and provides the property values for configuration of the declared beans by a property file. By *context:property-placeholder* Spring initializes all the variables with the concrete values when it creates the application context in memory.

```xml
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:myapp-configuration.properties" />
<import resource="classpath*:myapp-persistence-context.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath*:myapp-service-context.xml"/>
```

For the development profile the concrete *myapp-configuration.properties* may look like:

```
solr.serverUrl=http://localhost:8983/solr
jdbc.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
jdbc.driverClassName=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
jdbc.url=jdbc:hsqldb:mem:myapp
jdbc.username=sa
jdbc.password=
```

This configuration is imo straight forward and works - without view. The problem arises when *org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter* comes into play.

**Problem description**

*OpenSessionInViewFilter* ensures that instances in the object graph which are not loaded within an open transaction during the controller processing can be lazily loaded, if the view tries to display these objects´ content (see [[1]](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/OpenSessionInViewFilter.html)). As often described this filter is declared in the delpoyment descriptor *web.xml* (see [[2]](http://blog.gmorales.net/2012/03/how-to-solve-orghibernatelazyinitializa.html)):

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

If *myapp-persistence-context.xml* is included in *myapp-servlet.xml* like above so that *context:property-placeholder* works, *OpenSessionInViewFilter* does not find the necessary *sessionFactory*. The reason seems to be that Spring first processes *web.xml* and then *myapp-servlet.xml*, which imports *myapp-persistence-context.xml*. Unfourtunately I can´t proof this guess by a reference. Following exception is thrown:

```
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [myapp] in context with path [/myapp] threw exception
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'sessionFactory' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:529)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1095)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:277)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1097)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.lookupSessionFactory(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:242)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.lookupSessionFactory(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:227)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:171)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Different application context parts are usually included by the deployment descriptor with a *ContextLoaderListener* and not by *myapp-servlet.xml*:

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath*:myapp-service-context.xml, 
        classpath*:myapp-persistence-context.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

With this configuration unfourtunately, Spring´ s *context:property-placeholder* mechanism seems not to work any more.

**Objective and Question**

Modules like *myapp-persistence*(.jar) and *myapp-service*(.jar) must be configurable at run-time with a property file by the referencing context, e.g. the application context of *myapp-web*(.war).

The question is: Is it possible to configure *OpenSessionInViewFilter* in Spring application context so that *context:property-placeholder* is still useable?

Or alternatively: How can variables in applicaton contexts be initialized by Spring at run-time, if application context parts are included in the deployment descriptor *web.xml*?

Fundamentally: Why is actually *OpenSessionInViewFilter* necessary to be configured, why Spring MVC does not transparently support view lazy loading out-of-the-box?

**Anticipating Remarks**

Property replacement at compile-time is not the point here. The profile dependent property file is already created with Maven Filtering.

Moving *dataSource* and *solrServer* declarations into *myapp-servlet.xml* as already proposed (see [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14391201), [[4]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8574736/3245495)) is not an acceptable solution, because it destroyes modularity and independent testability of *myapp-persistence*(.jar) and *myapp-service*(.jar) - actually the spirit of dependency injection!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Talking to a colleague brought the solution: `context:property-placeholder` remains useable if I use Spring´s interceptor instead of the Servlet-API´s filter mechanism. I removed the reference of *myapp-persistence-context.xml* in `contextConfigLocation` and  the `OpenSessionInViewFilter` from *web.xml* and declared an `OpenSessionInViewInterceptor` in *myapp-persistence-context.xml*:

```xml
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean id="openSessionInViewInterceptor" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewInterceptor">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

With *myapp-persistence-context.xml* in the classpath of *myapp-persistence*(.jar) and the import statement in *myapp-servlet.xml* as described above, Spring replaces all property variables with the values in *myapp-configuration.properties* at run-time as intended. Modularity is saved at its best! [Will Keeling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2091925/will-keeling)´s [externalization of the property file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21443976/3245495) completes the project setup.

See also the discussion [Spring HandlerInterceptor vs Servlet Filters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8006367) and the [Spring doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/OpenSessionInViewInterceptor.html).

Comment: Your friend has show you the right way to handle hibernate sessions inside any application. I usually prefer the Interceptor way, because It is a safer approach, to have a losely coupled architecture, with only some spring beans to configure. Nowadays, use the Java config style, it is safer than *any* XML configuration.

Answer (score -1):

You should certainly keep the `sessionFactory` and non-web related beans in the root application context as defined by the `contextConfigLocation` in the `web.xml`. Apart from the modularity aspect (as you mention), the `OpenSessionInViewFilter` needs it this way because it looks for the `sessionFactory` in the root web application context and [it will error if it can't find it there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574552/spring-hibernate-lazy-loading-sessionfactory-and-opensessioninviewfilter) - as you discovered. So your `contextConfigLocation` setup is the correct way to go.

`PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` is a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` which means it works within the context of the bean factory in which it is defined. In this case, it is defined in  *myapp-servlet.xml* which means it will work within the web context but it won't resolve the placeholders in the root application context (where the `dataSource` and `solrServer` are defined).

My suggestion would be to move the `<context:property-placeholder>` from the web to the root application context - but parameterize the `location` allowing this to be set by the enclosing app. For example, you could add this to your *myapp-service-context.xml*

```
<context:property-placeholder location="${props.file}"/>
```

And then you can leave it to the *myapp-web.war* (or whatever the parent app happens to be) to set the location of the file. For example, this could be done as a system property:

```
-Dprops.file=file:C:/myapp-configuration.properties
```

Comment: This is a nice solution because configuration is completely externalized. Thanks!